# $A_{ij}=i-j$, for $i , j = 1, ..., n$. What is the rank of $A$? ($n\geq 2$).

Tags: linear-algebra

$n$ linear functionals are given as follows on $F^n$.

$$f_i(x_1, ..., x_n) = \sum_{j=1}^n(i-j)x_j,\ \ 1\leq i\leq n $$

And the dimension of the subspace annihilated by $f_1, ..., f_n$ is asked. I know this space is equal to the solution space of the system $Ax=0$, for the defined matrix in the question. So, if I find the rank of $A$, I have the solution.

> I should mention that I just saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074979/given-n-linear-functionals-f-kx-1-dotsc-x-n-sum-j-1n-k-jx-j-what) which makes my question somehow duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that $A$ is invertible for $n=2$. Now let $n\ge3$. And take $i\ge 3$.
Then
$$
a_{ij} - a_{1j} = i-1, \ a_{2j}-a_{1j} = 1,
$$
which implies
$$
a_{ij} - a_{1j}- (i-1)(a_{2j}-a_{1j}) =0.
$$
So rank of $A$ is two, as the first two rows are clearly linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks. Then, do you have any idea to find the subspace annihilated by $f_1, ..., f_n$?

Comment: If rank of $A$ is two, then the dimension of the solution space of $AX=0$ is $n-2$. Is this the one I am looking for?

Comment: @Majid yes, $AX = 0$ is actually two linear equations with $n$ variables

Answer (score 4):

For $n>2$ we have 
$$
A_{i,j} + A_{i+2,j} - 2A_{i+1,j} = 0,
$$
so "$i$-th row plus $(i+2)$-th row minus $2\times (i+1)$-th row" is zero, and thus $\det A = 0$ (if $n>2$). For example, if $n = 3$, we have
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
2 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = 0.
$$